# Deleting the rows that are only one line which is the header

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete the rows that have only one line which is the header, and then for the ones remaining have a 2 blank space.

[image]

```vb
Sub deletehead()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set wshh = Worksheets("Nenuco")
    i = LastRow
    For i = LastRow To 1
        
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("E" & i).Value) Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        
        Else
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select

        End If
        i = ActiveCell.Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to select the last row of column E where are the digits and see if there is a number.
If there is not a number delete the row and go to the next cell that is not blank which will be the upper table.
If there is a number don't delete it and go 2 times xlup to be located in the upper table.
Do this until row 1.

I would like to delete rows 1 and 13
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code, what you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? Do you mean that what you want is to delete rows with columns in blank?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I mean that i want to delete the rows that have only the header, so only keeping the headers for the ones that have info below

Comment: Are all the header lines the same?

Comment: The structure yes but it can change row because I also want to do it in other sheets

Answer (score 0):

If these assumptions are incorrect, the solution may need modification, although it does work on your example to remove rows 1 and 13.

- The first four columns of the first row will always be a Header
- The Headers will be the same throughout the table

Your problem can be solved using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select All the rows and columns in your data table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`

  - Be sure to deSELECT `my table has headers` check box
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

//First row, first four columns, should always be a header row
    Headers = Record.RemoveFields(Source{0}, List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(Source))),
    
//Remove Header rows if blank below
//Generate a list of Records (rows) to be retained
    #"Retained Records" =  List.RemoveNulls(
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[rr=if List.NonNullCount(Record.FieldValues(Source{1})) = 0 then 0 else null, idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(Source),
            each [rr=if Record.RemoveFields(Source{[idx]+1}, List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(Source))) = Headers and   
                        List.NonNullCount(Record.FieldValues(Source{[idx]+2})) = 0 then [idx]+1 else null, idx=[idx]+1],
            each if [rr]=null then Source{[idx]} else null)),

//Generate resulting table
    #"Headers Removed" = Table.FromRecords(#"Retained Records")
in
    #"Headers Removed"
```

[image]

***Note that this problem can be solved using Excel's built-in `Advanced Filter` with a Formula as the Criteria, using the same algorithm of checking if some row is a Header row and the next line is blank.***

- Assumptions as above
- Made up Headers in row `31` (as in screenshot above)
- Data in `A32:E48`
- Criteria range `A24:A25`
- Criteria formula `=AND(NOT((A32:D32=$A$32:$D$32)*(A33:D33="")))`